# AMQP 1.0 Library for Python

Tags: python, activemq-classic, amqp

I'm looking for a AMQP 1.0 compliant Python library. I've gone through several libraries but they all seem to support only AMQP 0.9.1.

- amqp - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqp/1.4.7
- pika - https://github.com/pika/pika
- amqplib - https://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/

Puka (https://github.com/majek/puka) doesn't seem to mention the specific AMQP version it supports, but it only says it's a RabbitMQ client.

Comment: AMQP 0.9.1 and AMQP 1.0 are two completely different types of standards that does not try to solve the same issues. The fact that AMQP 1.0 was named just that is very confusing. http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/AMQP-1-0-Support-td7819.html

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Kaushal28 Apache Qpid as the answer suggests seems to be the only approach. I was not able to follow through with this though.

Comment: yes thanks. Just configured Qpid proton. and it's working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Apache Qpid](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) project offers clients for a number of programming languages that are AMQP 1.0 compliant.  There are probably others out there as well but the Qpid bits are nice as they are all based around a single core called Proton so the API is pretty consistent across client implementations.

Answer (score 3):

For AMQP 1.0 I have found uamqp: https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python (MIT License)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I am currently trying to connect to a RabbitMQ with AMQP1.0 plugin using this library, but without success. Were you able to connect? I would love to see some working example!